# PropertyGrid: Trouble with ExpandableObjectConverter

Tags: c#, propertygrid

I have created a class to display in a `PropertyGrid` which contains another class; I would like this class to be expandable so I tried adding the `[TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]` but it doesn't seem to work. Here is a simple example I tried:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.propertyGrid1.SelectedObject = new Class1();
    }
}

public class Class1
{
    string name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return this.name; }
        set { this.name = value; }
    }

    Class2 class2;

    public Class2 Class2
    {
        get { return this.class2; }
        set { this.class2 = value; }
    }
}

[TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]
public class Class2
{
    string stuff = "none";

    public string Stuff
    {
        get { return this.stuff; }
        set { this.stuff = value; }
    }
}
```

When displayed in the property grid, the `Class2` property of the `Class1` instance isn't expandable. Any idea on why this isn't working?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your property of type Class2 is not expanding because it is null. Just instantiate your property and all will be fine:

```
Class2 class2 = new Class2();
```

Comment: (locks self in closet of shame)... Thank you.